# Azure Job BlobTrigger path to have year month day format in the path

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

I am writing a web job that processes data dumped to the azure storage account in a format
           mystorage/data/{yyyy}/{MM}/{dd}/app.csv

What I want to do now in Blobtrigger is the following

```
  void Foo( BlobTrigger(" mystorage/data/{yyyy}/{MM}/{dd}/app.csv") Stream message, TextWriter log)
{
}
```

Is this possible? I want todays date to be parsed to yyyy, MM, and dd. Basically the blob should be triggered based on today's date which is part of the path of the file in the blob

Comment: You can't create blobs as file structure. You should take a look at File Storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction

Comment: Absolutely that is possible. I have ADF piple that is creating that structure in the blob storage account

Comment: Do you really need to create subfolder/container ? maybe you should just use a file pattern like that  {yyyy}-{MM}-{dd}-app.csv. I don't think blobtrigger will handle dynamic folder name, just dynamic blob name

Comment: @Thomas That is good idea but does the blobtrigger know {yyyy} means year or does is it just stick in any string?

Comment: I think just stick to any string, it is usefull if you d like to add a parameter to your function definition like void Foo( BlobTrigger(" mystorage/data/{yyyy}/{MM}/{dd}/app.csv") Stream message, string yyyy, string MM, string dd, TextWriter log) but not sure if it works for container name

Comment: I think I saw also BlobTrigger is not reliable. The Azure SDK uses logs to trigger blob events such as create , or update. There is no guarantee that this will happen. I decided in ADF to create a Queue after transferring the data as part of the pipeline and then use QueueTrigger but still might face the same issue. I will find out

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can trigger an Azure Function for such blobs. Here is a sample function definition:

```
[FunctionName("Blob")]
public static void Blob(
    [BlobTrigger("mystorage/data/{yyyy}/{MM}/{dd}/app.csv")] Stream message, 
    string yyyy,
    string MM,
    string dd,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Found {yyyy}-{MM}-{dd}");
}
```

It will be triggered if you create a blob called e.g. `data/2017/09/12/app.csv` in the container `mystorage`.

Note that it won't validate the date parts, it will take them as plain strings: for instance,  `data/A/B/C/app.csv` will also be processed. You could change the type of input parameters to `int`, but that will cause a binding exception for non-numeric paths. Parsing the date manually should be trivial though:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse($"{yyyy}-{MM}-{dd}", out DateTime date))
{
    log.Info($"Found {date}");
}
```